# new column with each element as a list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data frames where I want to add new columns, and in this new column each element should be a string for example of two rows,

```
df
           index colA colB 
           0     a    a1
           1     b    b1
```

Now I can add new column as

```
df['colC']=5
           index colA colB colC
           0     a    a1   5
           1     b    b1   5
```

now I want to add a third column with each element as list

```
           index colA colB colC
           0     a    a1   ['m','n','p']
           1     b    b1   ['m','n','p']
```

but,

```
df['colC']=['m','n','p'] is giving error
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

which is obvious.

```
I know in our example I can do

df['colC']=[['m','n','p'],['m','n','p']]
```

But I want to set each element to same list of strings, when I do not know number of rows.
Can anyone suggest something easy to achieve this.

Comment: Side note: putting lists in dataframes is not recommended. You will lose all vectorised functionality for the series in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `object`(`list`) to cell is tricky

```
df['colC']=[['m','n','p']]*len(df)
```

Or

```
df['colC'] = [list('mnp') for _ in range(len(df))]
```

df returns:

```
   index colA colB       colC
0      0    a   a1  [m, n, p]
1      1    b   b1  [m, n, p]
```

Comment: This is helpful, Thanks

Comment: Sure. New to stack exchange

Comment: @HiteshRahangdale no worry :-) happy coding